# Polymer - Pass dom-repeated item inside on-click function

Tags: polymer-1.0

How do I pass a dom-repeated item inside a function in on-click? My code doesn't work:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">

 <template>

   <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{stuff}}>

    <paper-button on-click="_myFunction(item.name)">{{item.name}}</paper-button>

   </template>

 </template>

</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({

    is: 'my-element',

    ready: function() {
      this.stuff = [
        { id: 0, name: 'Red' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Blue' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Yellow' },
      ];
    },

    _myFunction: function(color) {
      console.log('You pressed button ' + color);
    },

  })
</script>
```

Or is there a better approach in achieving something like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't pass arguments directly to on-click methods, but you can retrieve the item clicked inside a dom-repeat template via the event :

```
<script>
 Polymer({

 is: 'my-element',

 ready: function() {
   this.stuff = [
     { id: 0, name: 'Red' },
     { id: 1, name: 'Blue' },
     { id: 2, name: 'Yellow' },
   ];
 },

 _myFunction: function(e) {
   console.log('You pressed button ' + e.model.item.name);
 },

});
</script>
```

See the relevant documentation [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#handling-events).

Comment: thanks, how can I pass the clicked item to a another element, where I can edit the content live, I mean that changes are bind with the original item?

Comment: attaching on-click is not better. Consider using on-tap which is uniform for both mobile and desktop.

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer**
The item is in the event parameter: `e.model.item`

**From the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#handling-events):**

> When you add a declarative event handler inside the 
>   template, the repeater adds a model property to each event sent to the
>   listener. The model is the scope data used to generate the template
>   instance, so the item data is model.item:

```
<dom-module id="simple-menu">

  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" id="menu" items="{{menuItems}}">
        <div>
          <span>{{item.name}}</span>
          <span>{{item.ordered}}</span>
          <button on-click="order">Order</button>
        </div>
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'simple-menu',
      ready: function() {
        this.menuItems = [
            { name: "Pizza", ordered: 0 },
            { name: "Pasta", ordered: 0 },
            { name: "Toast", ordered: 0 }
        ];
      },
      order: function(e) {
        var model = e.model;
        model.set('item.ordered', model.item.ordered+1);
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

> Note: The model property is not added for event listeners registered
>   imperatively (using addEventListener), or listeners added to one of
>   the  template's parent nodes. In these cases, you can use
>   the  modelForElement method to retrieve the model data
>   that generated a given element. (There are also corresponding
>   itemForElement and indexForElement methods.)